# A few pixels appear masking autocomplete webkit input

Tags: html, css

I'm hiding the autocomplete default design on input, everything look nice on light screen but on dark mode there are a few tiny pixels that appear on the input corners. I know that one solution is disabling the autocomplete, but I don't want that. Is there another solution than make the input absolute 100%x100% against the background input to hide the corners on the white line?

[image: Those tiny pixels can be seen when autocomplete is active]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the base theme of the provider had an border-radius by default. I just add `border-radius: 0 !important;` and it fix up.